# Is it possible to run the same custom validation method at multiple times (on)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ruby：2.5.3
Rails：6.0.0

You are creating a validation for a date.

The contents of the validation are

- The timing of A allows up to 45 days after. (= Max: Date.today + 45.days)
- The timing of B allows for 30 days before to 60 days after. (= Min: Date.today - 30.days ~ Max: Date.today + 45.days)

I created the following to implement the above, but at this time `future_date` was not executed at both timing a and b.

```
validate :future_date, on: :a
with_options on: :b do |b|
  b.validate :future_date
  b.validate :past_date
end
```

As a solution, I created another method as follows and included `future_date` in it.

```
validate :future_date, on: :a
validate :between_date, on: :b

def between_date
 past_date
 future_date
end
```

It didn't work, but the first method seems to be more intuitive.

【Question】

- Can the same validation method be executed at multiple times (on)?
- Or is there a suitable alternative to that?

If you have any questions, please ask.

Comment: A and B are custom contexts ?

Comment: yes A and B are custom contexts. Use as in `self.valid?(:a)`, `self.valid?(:b)`